# Javascript loop based on selected index in seperate dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a select list like below:-

```
<select id="countryData">   
    <option>England</option>           
    <option>France</option>          
    <option>Germany</option>         
</select>
```

I also have a variable declared with data for each country in the list e.g:-

```
var England = {};
England['Spain'] = 45;
England['Denmark'] = 50;
```

I need a way so that I display a list of countries and values for that country depending on what is selected in the drop down box. e.g. England is selected in dropdown:-

```
ENGLAND

Spain   45
Denmark 50
```

My javascript skills are awful unfortunately, so far I have been getting the selected value from the dropdown using:-

```
$("#countryData option:selected").text()
```

However that is literally populated with 'England' for example, as a string, so i'm not sure how to reference the array 'England' in my for loop which was going something like:-

```
for (var name in $("#countryData option:selected").text()) {
            document.write($("#countryData option:selected").text()[name]);
    }
```

I am probably just going about it the wrong way, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your variable is an object and, but declaring it as `England` is an error, you can declare it as `Country` so you can put properties like `country_name` `ZIP_code` and so on.

Comment: define a varible like `var myVar = window[$("#countryData option:selected").text()]`, then use the variable for your operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `document.write()` after the page is loaded, it will overwrite the contents of the page. Use jQuery's methods for appending elements to the DOM.

`.text()` returns a string, not an object, so you can't use `for-in` with it.

If you want to use the country from the drop-down as a key to look something up, you need to have that as the property name in an object:

```
var countries = {
    England: {
        Spain: 45,
        Denmark: 50
    }
    France: {
        Spain: 30,
        Portugal: 40
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can do as follows:

```
var country = $("#countryData option:selected").text());
$.each(countries[country], function(name, value) {
    $("#resultList").append("<li>" + name + " " + value + "</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object that will keep the `countries` and you can add properties that can be accessed like this `countries['England']`.

This property can be an array an have other objects too, and you can acces them like this `countries['England']['Spain']`.

**Note:** I made a function `display` that display the countries with `<p />`,  this logic can be changed with a `table` or something else..

```js
var countries = {
  England: [],
};
countries['England']['Spain'] = 45;
countries['England']['Denmark'] = 50;
countries['France'] = [];
countries['France']['Denmark'] = 130;

var $display = $('#display');
var $ddlCountry = $("#countryData");

$ddlCountry.change(function(){
  var selected = $("#countryData option:selected").text();
  display(selected);
});

function display(selected) {
  var selectedCountries = countries[selected];
  $display.empty();
  $display.append('<p>' + selected + '</p>');
  for(var country in selectedCountries)
  {
    var value = '<p>' + country + ' ' + selectedCountries[country] + '</p>';
    $display.append(value);
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countryData">   
    <option>England</option>           
    <option>France</option>          
    <option>Germany</option>         
</select>

<div id="display"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will be handy in the future as I was planning on assigning a custom URL to each country in the sub list :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
var England = {};
England['Spain'] = 45;
England['Denmark'] = 50;

var selectedText = $("#countryData option:selected").text();
var result = eval(selectedText);
for (var key in result) {
    document.write(result[key] + "<br/>");
}
```

However, this is some very bad peace of code for many reasons. For example using eval() is not a good idea here.

Instead you should use something like this:

```
var options = {
    England : {
        Spain : 45,
        Denmark : 50
    },
    France : {
        //...
    },
    Germany : {
        //...
    }
};

var selectedText = $("#countryData option:selected").text();
var selectedOptData = options[selectedText];
for (var key in selectedOptData) {
    document.write(selectedOptData[key] + "<br/>");
}
```

This code is much better. Also consider the comments from the others to even improve the code a little more. But basically, I guess this is the answer to your question.

Furthermore, please consider using the value attribute of your option tags, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp for a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look into value attributes